# What is more efficient? A dict inside the class definition or dict inside a func definition?

Tags: python, memory

I have some object that will be always stored in memory and there will be thousands of instances, so it is important to use memory efficiently.

This object will use some dict like:

```
{
'text':doSomething,
'string':doAnotherThing,
'int':doSomethingCrazy
}
```

Of course i can put it OUT of the class, on the module level, so it for sure will be stored in memory only once, but I prefer to keep things together, so if it is used only in that class it looks better if it is kept inside class.

The question is, will it be stored in memory only once if i put the dict into the class definition?

```
class MyClass(object):
   thatDict={}
```

Or will be it stored in memory only once if i put it in the function definition?

```
class MyClass(object):
   def someFunc():       
      thatDict={}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put it inside a function, the dictionary will be recreated every single time the function is called.  This is a bit of a waste, especially of the dictionary is large:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def someFunc():       
        thatDict={} # recreated every function call
```

If you put it in a class definition, it is created once: when the module is loaded.

```
class MyClass(object):
    thatDict={} # Only one copy
```

You can also create it at file scope with the same effects:

```
thatDict={} # Only one copy
class MyClass(object):
    ...
```

Comment: So what happens if I edit that dict in one instance, it creates copy of it and while no edits made uses basic one?

Comment: As I said, there is only one copy.  If you edit it, another copy won't appear.

Comment: Seems strange to me, if you have obj1, and obj2. And edit self.thatdict in obj1, obj2 should not see that change. So i suppose, that when you edit via MyClass.thatdict there is indeed only one copy. But if you edit via self.thatdict another copy created. So this is based on assumption that on object creation copy not created before first edit...

Comment: no, when you declare the variable within the class it is like a static variable.  It wont magically create a new copy when using self.  If you want to create a local copy for the instance use the class'  `__init__`.

Comment: Oh... So i have always repeat declarations inside init in case i need each instance to have own property? I mean this already does not apply subject of question, but i should review my code if I used "self.var" supposing that it has object scope. Thanks!